# Changing error delimiter to empty in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i want to change the form error wrapper. I don't want any wrapper no div no `<p>` i have used this code `<?php echo form_error('inv_data_val','<div>','</div>'); ?>` it do adds the div but when i used `<?php echo form_error('inv_data_val','',''); ?>` it still shows p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
```

In your controller.

Comment: Is it possible that this delimiter could run for one field only?

Comment: Not using this method. No.